# FreeBSD 10.1 sound not working

Tags: drivers, freebsd, audio, intel

I am new to BSD and I am experimenting with getting an old(ish) Packard Bell desktop machine out of mothballs. The basic installation of FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE for amd64 seems to have gone fine, but I am stuck trying to get the sound card working.

The hardware is based on a Gigabyte motherboard hosting an Intel P4 processor, with integrated audio that uses the Intel High Definition Audio chipset. Under Linux the audio driver selected is `snd_hda_intel`, and the expectation under FreeBSD was that the `snd_hda` module would drive the audio.

After installing FreeBSD the sound was not working, but I followed the instructions available online in a number of places, using `kldload` to experiment with different drivers. I found that the amd64 GENERIC kernel already has `sound` and many sound drivers pre-loaded, so efforts to use `kldload` were misplaced. However, there is no record of any driver installed in the `/dev/sndstat` file, and attempts to make noise by typing `cat /random > /dev/dsp` return error messages saying the operation is not allowed.

What I want to know is, am I wasting my effort to get an ageing sound card working, or is there some trick I have missed?

**Further Information:**

This section was added at the suggestion of contributors to answers.

The output of `pciconf -lv` has the following entry for the audio controller:

```
hdac0@pci0:0:27:0:  class=0x040300 card=0xe0111631 chip=0x26688086 rev=0x03 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = '82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller'
    class      = multimedia
    subclass   = HDA
```

The output of `dmesg` is as follows:

```
Copyright (c) 1992-2014 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
FreeBSD is a registered trademark of The FreeBSD Foundation.
FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE #0 r274401: Tue Nov 11 21:02:49 UTC 2014
    root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC amd64
FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512
VT: running with driver "vga".
module_register: module at91_mci/mmc already exists!
Module at91_mci/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module sdhci_bcm/mmc already exists!
Module sdhci_bcm/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module sdhci_fdt/mmc already exists!
Module sdhci_fdt/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module sdhci_imx/mmc already exists!
Module sdhci_imx/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module sdhci_pci/mmc already exists!
Module sdhci_pci/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module sdhci_ti/mmc already exists!
Module sdhci_ti/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module ti_mmchs/mmc already exists!
Module ti_mmchs/mmc failed to register: 17
module_register: module mmc/mmcsd already exists!
Module mmc/mmcsd failed to register: 17
CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.06GHz (3059.06-MHz K8-class CPU)
  Origin = "GenuineIntel"  Id = 0xf41  Family = 0xf  Model = 0x4  Stepping = 1
  Features=0xbfebfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CLFLUSH,DTS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE>
  Features2=0x651d<SSE3,DTES64,MON,DS_CPL,TM2,CNXT-ID,CX16,xTPR>
  AMD Features=0x20100800<SYSCALL,NX,LM>
  TSC: P-state invariant
real memory  = 3221225472 (3072 MB)
avail memory = 3090366464 (2947 MB)
Event timer "LAPIC" quality 400
ACPI APIC Table: <GBT    AWRDACPI>
ioapic0 <Version 2.0> irqs 0-23 on motherboard
random: <Software, Yarrow> initialized
module_register_init: MOD_LOAD (vesa, 0xffffffff80d942e0, 0) error 19
kbd1 at kbdmux0
acpi0: <GBT AWRDACPI> on motherboard
acpi0: Power Button (fixed)
acpi0: reservation of 0, a0000 (3) failed
acpi0: reservation of 100000, bfef0000 (3) failed
cpu0: <ACPI CPU> on acpi0
attimer0: <AT timer> port 0x40-0x43 irq 0 on acpi0
Timecounter "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 0
Event timer "i8254" frequency 1193182 Hz quality 100
atrtc0: <AT realtime clock> port 0x70-0x73 irq 8 on acpi0
Event timer "RTC" frequency 32768 Hz quality 0
acpi_button0: <Power Button> on acpi0
pcib0: <ACPI Host-PCI bridge> port 0xcf8-0xcff on acpi0
pci0: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib0
pcib1: <PCI-PCI bridge> irq 16 at device 1.0 on pci0
pci1: <PCI bus> on pcib1
vgapci0: <VGA-compatible display> port 0x9000-0x90ff mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff,0xe5000000-0xe500ffff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci1
vgapci0: Boot video device
vgapci1: <VGA-compatible display> mem 0xe5010000-0xe501ffff at device 0.1 on pci1
hdac0: <Intel 82801F HDA Controller> mem 0xe6100000-0xe6103fff irq 16 at device 27.0 on pci0
uhci0: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-A> port 0xbc00-0xbc1f irq 23 at device 29.0 on pci0
usbus0 on uhci0
uhci1: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-B> port 0xb000-0xb01f irq 19 at device 29.1 on pci0
usbus1 on uhci1
uhci2: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-C> port 0xb400-0xb41f irq 18 at device 29.2 on pci0
usbus2 on uhci2
uhci3: <Intel 82801FB/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6) USB controller USB-D> port 0xb800-0xb81f irq 16 at device 29.3 on pci0
usbus3 on uhci3
ehci0: <Intel 82801FB (ICH6) USB 2.0 controller> mem 0xe6104000-0xe61043ff irq 23 at device 29.7 on pci0
usbus4: EHCI version 1.0
usbus4 on ehci0
pcib2: <ACPI PCI-PCI bridge> at device 30.0 on pci0
pci2: <ACPI PCI bus> on pcib2
ath0: <Atheros 9220> mem 0xe6000000-0xe600ffff irq 20 at device 0.0 on pci2
ath0: [HT] enabling HT modes
ath0: [HT] 1 stream STBC receive enabled
ath0: [HT] 1 stream STBC transmit enabled
ath0: [HT] 2 RX streams; 2 TX streams
ath0: AR9220 mac 128.2 RF5133 phy 13.0
ath0: 2GHz radio: 0x0000; 5GHz radio: 0x00c0
pci2: <simple comms, generic modem> at device 1.0 (no driver attached)
rl0: <RealTek 8139 10/100BaseTX> port 0xa400-0xa4ff mem 0xe6014000-0xe60140ff irq 21 at device 5.0 on pci2
miibus0: <MII bus> on rl0
rlphy0: <RealTek internal media interface> PHY 0 on miibus0
rlphy0:  10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto
rl0: Ethernet address: 00:14:85:40:4d:00
pci2: <serial bus, FireWire> at device 7.0 (no driver attached)
isab0: <PCI-ISA bridge> at device 31.0 on pci0
isa0: <ISA bus> on isab0
atapci0: <Intel ICH6 SATA150 controller> port 0x1f0-0x1f7,0x3f6,0x170-0x177,0x376,0xf000-0xf00f at device 31.2 on pci0
ata0: <ATA channel> at channel 0 on atapci0
ata1: <ATA channel> at channel 1 on atapci0
uart0: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
uart1: <16550 or compatible> port 0x2f8-0x2ff irq 3 on acpi0
ppc0: <Parallel port> port 0x378-0x37f,0x778-0x77b irq 7 drq 3 on acpi0
ppc0: Generic chipset (ECP/PS2/NIBBLE) in COMPATIBLE mode
ppc0: FIFO with 16/16/16 bytes threshold
ppbus0: <Parallel port bus> on ppc0
lpt0: <Printer> on ppbus0
lpt0: Interrupt-driven port
ppi0: <Parallel I/O> on ppbus0
atkbdc0: <Keyboard controller (i8042)> port 0x60,0x64 irq 1 on acpi0
atkbd0: <AT Keyboard> irq 1 on atkbdc0
kbd0 at atkbd0
atkbd0: [GIANT-LOCKED]
orm0: <ISA Option ROMs> at iomem 0xc0000-0xcbfff,0xcc000-0xd3fff,0xd4000-0xd4fff on isa0
p4tcc0: <CPU Frequency Thermal Control> on cpu0
random: unblocking device.
usbus0: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
fuse-freebsd: version 0.4.4, FUSE ABI 7.8
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
hdacc0: <Realtek ALC880 HDA CODEC> at cad 2 on hdac0
hdaa0: <Realtek ALC880 Audio Function Group> at nid 1 on hdacc0
usbus1: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus2: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
usbus3: 12Mbps Full Speed USB v1.0
ugen0.1: <Intel> at usbus0
uhub0: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus0
ugen1.1: <Intel> at usbus1
uhub1: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus1
ugen2.1: <Intel> at usbus2
uhub2: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus2
ugen3.1: <Intel> at usbus3
uhub3: <Intel UHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 1.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus3
usbus4: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
ugen4.1: <Intel> at usbus4
uhub4: <Intel EHCI root HUB, class 9/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus4
uhub0: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub1: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub2: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
uhub3: 2 ports with 2 removable, self powered
ada0 at ata0 bus 0 scbus0 target 0 lun 0
ada0: <ST3200826AS 3.03> ATA-7 SATA 1.x device
ada0: Serial Number 5ND1T70S
ada0: 150.000MB/s transfers (SATA, UDMA5, PIO 8192bytes)
ada0: 190782MB (390721968 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada0: Previously was known as ad0
cd0 at ata1 bus 0 scbus1 target 0 lun 0
cd0: <HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDR8163B 0N21> Removable CD-ROM SCSI-0 device 
cd0: 66.700MB/s transfers (UDMA4, ATAPI 12bytes, PIO 65534bytes)
cd0: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
cd1 at ata1 bus 0 scbus1 target 1 lun 0
cd1: <PHILIPS DVDR1628P1 Q2.4> Removable CD-ROM SCSI-0 device 
cd1: Serial Number V7121S52961724
cd1: 33.300MB/s transfers (UDMA2, ATAPI 12bytes, PIO 65534bytes)
cd1: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
Timecounter "TSC-low" frequency 1529530837 Hz quality 1000
Root mount waiting for: usbus4
Root mount waiting for: usbus4
Root mount waiting for: usbus4
uhub4: 8 ports with 8 removable, self powered
Root mount waiting for: usbus4
Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ada0p2 [rw]...
ugen0.2: <vendor 0x058f> at usbus0
umass0: <vendor 0x058f USB Reader, class 0/0, rev 1.10/1.00, addr 2> on usbus0
umass0:  SCSI over Bulk-Only; quirks = 0x4001
umass0:2:0:-1: Attached to scbus2
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 0
da0: <Generic USB SD Reader 1.00> Removable Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da0: Serial Number 2004888
da0: 1.000MB/s transfers
da0: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
da0: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
da1 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 1
da1: <Generic USB CF Reader 1.01> Removable Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da1: Serial Number 2004888
da1: 1.000MB/s transfers
da1: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
da1: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
da2 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 2
da2: <Generic USB SM Reader 1.02> Removable Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da2: Serial Number 2004888
da2: 1.000MB/s transfers
da2: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
da2: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
da3 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 3
da3: <Generic USB MS Reader 1.03> Removable Direct Access SCSI-0 device 
da3: Serial Number 2004888
da3: 1.000MB/s transfers
da3: Attempt to query device size failed: NOT READY, Medium not present
da3: quirks=0x2<NO_6_BYTE>
ugen3.2: <Logitech> at usbus3
wlan0: Ethernet address: 00:24:01:ee:97:ea
ums0: <Logitech USB-PS2 Optical Mouse, class 0/0, rev 2.00/11.10, addr 2> on usbus3
ums0: 3 buttons and [XYZ] coordinates ID=0
WARNING: attempt to domain_add(bluetooth) after domainfinalize()
```

As far as I can tell from the hieroglyphics on the motherboard, the board is a `Gigabyte GA-81915PM`. I hope that means more to someone than it does to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `snd_hda` driver was being loaded (it was), the lack of working sound indicates either a driver conflict or a bad default configuration. To bottom this out I added the following line to `/boot/loader.conf` to turn on verbose messages in `dmesg`:

```
boot_verbose="YES"
```

Doing this makes `dmesg` output much more useful, with all kinds of additional information (see [this link](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=snd_hda&sektion=&n=1) which turns out to be essential reading).

Extracting the useful stuff from `dmesg` gives me something like this:

```
hdac0: <Intel 82801F HDA Controller> mem 0xe6100000-0xe6103fff irq 16 at device 27.0 on pci0
hdac0: PCI card vendor: 0x1631, device: 0xe011
hdac0: HDA Driver Revision: 20120126_0002
hdac0: Config options: on=0x00000000 off=0x00000000
hdac0: attempting to allocate 1 MSI vectors (1 supported)
hdac0: using IRQ 256 for MSI
hdac0: Caps: OSS 4, ISS 4, BSS 0, NSDO 1, 64bit, CORB 256, RIRB 256
hdacc0: <Realtek ALC880 HDA CODEC> at cad 2 on hdac0
hdaa0: <Realtek ALC880 Audio Function Group> at nid 1 on hdacc0
hdaa0: Subsystem ID: 0x08800000
hdaa0: NumGPIO=2 NumGPO=0 NumGPI=0 GPIWake=0 GPIUnsol=1
hdaa0:  GPIO0: disabled
hdaa0:  GPIO1: disabled
hdaa0: Original pins configuration:
hdaa0: nid   0x    as seq device       conn  jack    loc        color   misc
hdaa0: 20 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 21 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 22 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 23 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 24 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 25 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 26 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 27 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 28 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 29 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 30 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 31 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: Patching widget caps nid=29 0x00400000 -> 0x00700000
hdaa0: Patched pins configuration:
hdaa0: nid   0x    as seq device       conn  jack    loc        color   misc
hdaa0: 20 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 21 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 22 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 23 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 24 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 25 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 26 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 27 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 28 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 30 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 31 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: Tracing input monitor
hdaa0: Tracing other input monitors
hdaa0: Tracing beeper
hdaa0: FG config/quirks: forcestereo ivref50 ivref80 ivref100 ivref
```

All the pins of the audio device have been assigned default values that render them disabled, so no device was configured.

To change the defaults to something sensible, modifications are needed to the boot-time configuration, which is done by adding some lines to `/boot/device.hints`. There seems to be a lot of flexibility here, but I tried the following, which was enough to get audio output working straight away:

```
hint.hdaa.0.nid20.config="as=1 seq=0 device=Speaker conn=Fixed loc=Onboard color=Unknown"
hint.hdaa.0.nid21.config="as=2 seq=0 device=Line-out conn=Jack loc=Rear color=Green"
hint.hdaa.0.nid27.config="as=2 seq=15 device=Headphones conn=Jack loc=Front color=Green"
```

Checking `dmesg` now yields:

```
hdac0: <Intel 82801F HDA Controller> mem 0xe6100000-0xe6103fff irq 16 at device 27.0 on pci0
hdac0: PCI card vendor: 0x1631, device: 0xe011
hdac0: HDA Driver Revision: 20120126_0002
hdac0: Config options: on=0x00000000 off=0x00000000
hdac0: attempting to allocate 1 MSI vectors (1 supported)
hdac0: using IRQ 256 for MSI
hdac0: Caps: OSS 4, ISS 4, BSS 0, NSDO 1, 64bit, CORB 256, RIRB 256
hdacc0: <Realtek ALC880 HDA CODEC> at cad 2 on hdac0
hdaa0: <Realtek ALC880 Audio Function Group> at nid 1 on hdacc0
hdaa0: Subsystem ID: 0x08800000
hdaa0: NumGPIO=2 NumGPO=0 NumGPI=0 GPIWake=0 GPIUnsol=1
hdaa0:  GPIO0: disabled
hdaa0:  GPIO1: disabled
hdaa0: Original pins configuration:
hdaa0: nid   0x    as seq device       conn  jack    loc        color   misc
hdaa0: 20 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 21 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 22 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 23 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 24 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 25 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 26 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 27 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 28 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 29 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 30 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: 31 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
hdaa0: Patching widget caps nid=29 0x00400000 -> 0x00700000
hdaa0: Patching pin config nid=20 0x00000000 -> 0x99100010
hdaa0: Patching pin config nid=21 0x00000000 -> 0x01004020
hdaa0: Patching pin config nid=27 0x00000000 -> 0x0220402f
hdaa0: Patched pins configuration:
hdaa0: nid   0x    as seq device       conn  jack    loc        color   misc
hdaa0: 20 99100010 1  0  Speaker       Fixed Unknown Onboard    Unknown 0
hdaa0: 21 01004020 2  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown Rear       Green   0
hdaa0: 22 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 23 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 24 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 25 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 26 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 27 0220402f 2  15 Headphones    Jack  Unknown Front      Green   0
hdaa0: 28 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 30 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 31 00000000 0  0  Line-out      Jack  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0 DISA
hdaa0: 2 associations found:
hdaa0: Association 0 (1) out:
hdaa0:  Pin nid=20 seq=0
hdaa0: Association 1 (2) out:
hdaa0:  Pin nid=21 seq=0
hdaa0:  Pin nid=27 seq=15
hdaa0: Tracing association 0 (1)
hdaa0:  Pin 20 traced to DAC 2
hdaa0: Association 0 (1) trace succeeded
hdaa0: Tracing association 1 (2)
hdaa0:  Pin 21 traced to DAC 3
hdaa0:  Pin 27 traced to DAC 3 and hpredir 0
hdaa0: Association 1 (2) trace succeeded
hdaa0: Looking for additional DAC for association 0 (1)
hdaa0: Looking for additional DAC for association 1 (2)
hdaa0: Tracing input monitor
hdaa0: Tracing other input monitors
hdaa0: Tracing beeper
hdaa0:  nid 29 traced to out
hdaa0: Pin sense: nid=20 sense=0xffffffff (connected)
hdaa0: Headphones redirection for association 1 nid=27 using unsolicited responses.
hdaa0: Redirect output to: main
hdaa0: FG config/quirks: forcestereo ivref50 ivref80 ivref100 ivref
pcm0: <Realtek ALC880 (Onboard Analog Speaker)> at nid 20 on hdaa0
pcm1: <Realtek ALC880 (Analog 2.0+HP)> at nid 21,27 on hdaa0
```

showing that the re-configured pins have allowed the creation of two audio output devices, `pcm0` and `pcm1`. The contents of `/dev/sndstat` confirm this:

```
Installed devices:
pcm0: <Realtek ALC880 (Onboard Analog Speaker)> (play) default
pcm1: <Realtek ALC880 (Analog 2.0+HP)> (play)
```

Making the microphone work is left as an exercise for the reader!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the FreeBSD documentation, you should issue:

```
# kldload snd_hda
```

then do

```
# cat /dev/sndstat
```

If that does not work, try loading all drivers:

```
# kldload snd_driver
# cat /dev/sndstat
```

Do the following to test sound:

```
# cat /random >/dev/dsp
```

More information:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/sound-setup.html

If this does not work, you can try:

```
pciconf -lv
```

This will give more details on the exact chipset used in the onboard sound card.

You could also post the output of `dmesg` when you load the kernel module.

Please provide the exact model of motherboard as well.

Comment: This is a great answer that missed the point of my question, which was that I have tried all these suggestions I had already found online, and I was seeking inspiration for what to do next to get the sound working. Thanks for your response, as it has helped me clarify my question (see heavily edited OP).

Comment: Thanks for the additions to your answer. Please find a new section in the OP where I have provided the information you requested.